# Finding the relative position of elements in a list using SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to return subjects based on the relative position of their subjects in an ordered list.

A subject can be associated with multiple objects (via a single predicate) and all objects are in an ordered list. Given a reference object in this list I'd like to return the subjects in order of relative distance of their objects from the reference object.

```
:a : :x     
:b : :v
:b : :z
:c : :v
:c : :y

:ls :list (:v :w :x :y :z)
```

Taking x as our starting object in the list, the code below returns

```
:a :x :0
:c :y :1
:b :v :2
:b :z :2
:c :v :2
```

Instead of returning all positions I would like only the objects relating to the subject's minimum object 'distance' to be returned (which may mean up to two objects per subject - both up and down the list). So I'd like to return

```
:a :x :0
:c :y :1
:b :v :2
:b :z :2
```

The code so far...
(with a lot of help from [Find lists containing ALL values in a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027230/find-lists-containing-all-values-in-a-set) and [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523804/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-rdf-collection-in-sparql))

```
SELECT ?s ?p (abs(?refPos-?pos) as ?dif) 
WHERE {
      :ls :list/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?o .
      ?s : ?o .
      {
      SELECT ?o (count(?mid) as ?pos) ?refPos 
      WHERE {
            [] :list/rdf:rest* ?mid . ?mid rdf:rest* ?node .
            ?node rdf:first ?o .
            {
            SELECT ?o (count(?mid2) as ?refPos)
            WHERE {
                  [] :list/rdf:rest* ?mid2 . ?mid2 rdf:rest* ?node2 .
                  ?node2 rdf:first :x .
                  }
            }
            }
            GROUP BY ?o
      }
      }
      GROUP BY ?s ?o
      ORDER BY ?dif
```

I've been trying to get a minimum ?dif (difference/distance) by grouping by ?s but because I then have to apply this (something like ?dif = ?minDif) to the ?s ?o grouping from earlier I don't know how to go back and forward between these two groupings.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide

Comment: Are you sure that this is a proper use case for SPARQL? Sounds more like graph traversal engines like Cypher or Gremlin would work better here.

Comment: Thanks for those recommendations @AKSW. I wanted to incorporate the hierarchy a list provides into my SPARQL queries, but I'll look into graph traversal engines if I continue with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed to compound a solution is yet another one Joshua Taylor's answer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472717/7879193) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37865305/7879193).

Here below I'm using Jena functions, but I hope the idea is clear.

**Query 1**

```sql
PREFIX list: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/list#>
SELECT ?s ?el ?dif {
    ?s : ?el .
    :ls :list/list:index (?pos ?el) .
    :ls :list/list:index (?ref :x) .
    BIND (ABS(?pos -?ref) AS ?dif) 
    {
    SELECT ?s (MIN (?dif_) AS ?dif) WHERE {
        ?s : ?el_ .
        :ls :list/list:index (?pos_ ?el_) .
        :ls :list/list:index (?ref_ :x) .
        BIND (ABS(?pos_ - ?ref_) AS ?dif_)
        } GROUP by ?s
    }
}
```

**Query 2**

```sql
PREFIX list: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/list#>    
SELECT ?s ?el ?dif {
    ?s : ?el .
    :ls :list/list:index (?pos ?el) .
    :ls :list/list:index (?ref :x) .
    BIND (ABS(?pos -?ref) AS ?dif) 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
        ?s : ?el_ .
        :ls :list/list:index (?pos_ ?el_) .
        BIND (ABS(?pos_ - ?ref) AS ?dif_) .
        FILTER(?dif_ < ?dif)                                           
    }
}
```

**Update**

Query 1 can be rewritten in this way:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?s ?el ?dif {
  ?s : ?el 
  { select (count(*) as ?pos) ?el {[] :list/rdf:rest*/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?el} group by ?el }
  { select (count(*) as ?ref)     {[] :list/rdf:rest*/rdf:rest*/rdf:first :x} } 
  BIND (ABS(?pos - ?ref) AS ?dif) 
  {
  SELECT ?s (MIN(?dif_) AS ?diff) {
    ?s : ?el_ 
    { select (count(*) as ?pos_) ?el_ {[] :list/rdf:rest*/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?el_} group by ?el_ }
    { select (count(*) as ?ref_)      {[] :list/rdf:rest*/rdf:rest*/rdf:first :x} } 
    BIND (ABS(?pos_ - ?ref_) AS ?dif_)
    } GROUP by ?s
  }
  FILTER (?dif = ?diff)
}
```

**Notes**

- As you can see, this is not what SPARQL was designed for. For example, Blazegraph supports Gremlin...
- Possibly this is not what RDF was designed for. Or try other modeling approach: do you really need RDF lists?
- I haven't tested the above query in Virtuoso.

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav Kralin, I've just been playing with straight SPARQL (hence the verbose position queries).

Comment: Thanks again @Stanislav Kralin. I just wanted to explore some data using the hierarchy the list provides (while becoming more familiar with SPARQL). If it looks promising and I continue with this approach I'll check out Gremlin. Also, I was just running these queries in RDFLib and they all work fine.